# Can I use wildcards in netrw?

Tags: vim, netrw

I may be doing everything wrong and I have the feeling that the question I am asking is really basic but I cannot seem to find the answer anywhere.

When I browse a folder in order to open a file I do `:e .` and the current directory shows up.  However I would like to filter the folder view by lets say just *.txt files.  How can I get netrw to just show the *.txt files in that directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to do this it seems is to open the browser however you wish (`:e .` works), then hit <kbd>Ctrl-h</kbd>.  This will bring up a prompt that allows you to edit netrw's "ignore list".  Here you can put a pattern like ".txt$".  Once you enter the pattern, cycle through netrw's hide method using <kbd>a</kbd> while on the file tree.

This is a little clunky but after playing with it for a few minutes it's actually quite comfortable.

You'll definitely want to read up on the following help topics:

- `:help g:netrw_list_hide`
- `:help netrw-ctrl-h`
- `:help netrw-a`

Comment: Now you have piqued my interest.  How else does one open the browser besides `:e .`?  The `Ctrl-h` thing worked perfectly.  Thanks.

Comment: Check out `:help netrw-browse-cmds`